# How do I change 'name' product attribute to storeview?

Tags: import, products, localisation

I have a multi-store set up (Magento Community Edition) and want to translate one of the stores to French.

I've exported the product data and had it translated but before I tried importing I thought I'd check the product settings. It seems I need to change the scope of the relevant attributes (name, description, short description for example) to "Store View" before I import.

This works fine for description and short description but I can't change the name attribute and get the message:

> The attribute code 'name' is reserved by system. Please try another attribute code

How do I change this so I can use the translated product names?

Any other quick tips on product data importing from folks who have done it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the Scope within `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes`
I assume this is where you got that error message? However, I just changed it in one of my Magento stores with no error messages.

The only thing I'd suggest is to change them in the Database but that would be a bit risky if Magento won't let you change it.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly where I got the error message. I've changed other attributes but this particular one seems to be problematic. Might consider a database change as a last resort but I suspect you are right in that there is probably a very good reason why Magento won't let me change it.

Comment: I can change the scope there just fine, too. The error message sort of suggests you are trying to make a second attribute with the code `name` or alter the code `name` of this attribute...

Comment: Yeah, Magento appears to suggest that's what I'm doing though I'm quite simply selecting 'Store View' from the Scope dropdown and saving. Nothing else is changed.

Comment: I tried researching further into this but ultimately arrived at the decision to try changing this in the database which proved to be successful. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the storeview you want to make edits for in the right upper corner, deactivate the checkbox `use default` and put your translated name for the french store view and the orignal name for the english store.

Comment: The problem is I don't get that option at all as the attribute is marked as global. This is why I'm trying to change the scope to "Store View" so I get that option.

Comment: I see. The attribute is marked storeView by default on my stores, though.